Accessibility Permission revoke
After auto-updating the application, the accessibility permission is automatically revoked, even though it was already granted. The device's OS is Android 10. There are multiple devices on which my application is installed, but after the auto-update, on some devices, the accessibility permission is revoked automatically.
In which cases is the accessibility permission revoked automatically?
I tried the same test case but did not face this issue. This issue occurs in production.

Which permission did you request exactly?

android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS
